# Having issues with python project structure

Tags: python, project

I'm currently on exercise 46 of learn python the hard way and I've been having serious issues getting my sample project structure to work the way it's described in the chapter. First off, my structure looks like this.

```
 Kilos/
      Kilos/
          __init__.py
      bin/
          Birds.py
      docs/
      setup.py
      tests/
          __init__.py
          Kilos_tests.py
```

Secondly, my setup.py script looks like this.

```
try:
    from setuptools import setup
except ImportError:
    from distutils.core import setup

config = {
    'description': 'Kilos',
    'author': 'My Name',
    'url': 'URL to get it at.',
    'download_url': 'Where to download it.',
    'author_email': 'My email.',
    'version': '0.1',
    'install_requires': ['nose'],
    'packages': ['Kilos'],
    'scripts': ['bin/Birds.py'],
    'name': 'Kilos'
}

setup(**config)
```

So here's my issue. Unless I move Birds.py from /bin to the root Kilos folder that contains 'setup.py' and change the the location of it in my setup I can't import it at all after installing my module. I want to be able to access Birds.py while it's in the bin folder. I know I'm most definitely overlooking something really simple here but it's driving me crazy. If anyone can tell me where I went wrong with this it would be GREATLY appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Files in the `bin/` folder are not meant to be imported, they are meant to be installed as programs to be executed.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried with an __init__.py file in the bin folder?

Also, the documentation says this ...

> Scripts are files containing Python source code, intended to be started from the command line

[documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/distutils/setupscript.html)

So, maybe it's not intended to let you import them once they're install.

Maybe what you want is ... `py_modules = ['bin.Birds']`  with an __init__.py file in bin/

Comment: I just added an init to the bin folder and unfortunately have the same result.

Comment: did you try with `py_modules : ['bin.Birds']`
and include the \__init__.py

Comment: The `bin/` folder is for binaries/programs not for modules.  If `Birds` is a module intended to be imported by other modules `bin/` simply isn't the right place for that file.